# Visual Studio still referring to packages I already uninstalled

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm still very new to Visual Studio and C#, and I recently encountered a problem:
I migrated packages.config to PackageReference, then rolled that action back (because it didn't work with WindowsAPICodePack), reinstalled all NuGet packages with Package Manager Console, then removed all packages manually with Package Manager to start all over again, but the code

> using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack;

still somehow refers to non-existing package. How to fix that?

References

[image: References]

NuGet packages installed

[image: NuGet packages installed]

Comment: using isn't a reference to a package, but importing types from a namespace (which is often the same name). You can simply remove the using statement, in't it ?

Comment: Check .csproj file. Maybe there is still reference to the package.

Comment: Nope, there's nothing in .csproj file about removed packages; in packages folder too

Comment: Maybe `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell`, which you have as reference, has the namespace `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack`.

Comment: The general question is how to remove it.